# I used 45 minute medium set. Can I use drywall mud to “finish” it?

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

I used a 45 minute medium compound instead of drywall mud. I realized my mistake and have tried to scrape it off. It now looks terrible.

Can I now used the drywall mud to smooth it out?

Comment: What, precisely, is the product you used? "Setting" drywall compound would be fine (but then, why did you consider it a mistake?) Artists medium would be less suitable. It's unclear what you actually mean.

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to a fast setting joint compound that comes in a bag and mixed with water? Yes you can. I typically use the fast set mud since it does not shrink much and sets fast, so I can add a coat of regular mud over that since it is much easier to sand than the fast set mud.

Answer (score 0):

If you applied too much, you need to sand it off, not just apply more of another product.